# NSURLSessionDownloadTasks halt after device auto-lock or 30 minutes of backgrounded activity

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am developing a downloader app for a client, and need to be able to background download tasks for very large fiels (ex, 3GB). I am using a background-configured `NSURLSession` and `NSURLSessionDownloadTasks`. It is working great, except I often notice that the downloads will halt (stop reporting progress, never complete), when the device auto-locks, or after 30 minutes of being backgrounded.

Is anyone else seeing this issue, or aware of any limitations with background-enabled `NSURLSession`?

Thanks

Comment: Is the device connected to wifi or 3G when the stop occurs? Could be an Apple restriction or actually a bug. `NSURLSession` is a new technology, and there can be bugs that need to be ironed out.

Answer (score 0):

There are strict guidelines on apps operating in the background. You should read through this documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3

There are only certain classes of apps that are allowed to operate for extended periods of time in the background: VoIP and Location-Based Applications are the only ones that can operate for periods of time you are suggesting. This is due to considerations like battery life, etc.

Comment: I understand that there are strict restrictions, however I am using NSURLSession with the background configuration, as specified in the Apple URL System Loading Guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html)

NSURLSession is a different approach from the traditional approach of using background tasks, which are subject to the backgrounding rules.

Comment: @AhmedB NSURLSession provides lot of background support but there are many issues concerning it.Check the Apple Developer Forum for problems related to NSURLSession.[Link]https://devforums.apple.com/message/948981#948981